# Remove event listener doesn't work as it should

Tags: javascript

I simply tried to addEventListener and removeEventListener to element, but it doesn't remove.

I suppose that the problem could be with parameters, but I used them to follow the DRY. So I could simply reuse it like nextSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent(event, nextSection)) and so on and so on so I do not need any if statements or stuff like that.

*** EDIT ***

I made some more examples of elements that I will be using. There’s a chance, that there will be event more. If I do not use parameter, there would be a lot more of functions. Also, there will be click instead of mouse events on mobile, so I need to remove them.

As I understand now, the problem is with return statement. If I use event instead of parameter and so event.target I get some weird bug.

```
const loginSection = document.querySelector('#js-login-section');
const searchSection = document.querySelector('#js-search-section');
const shoppingBagSection = document.querySelector('#js-shopping-bag-section');
const wishlistSection = document.querySelector('#js-wishlist-section');

function showContent(element) {
    return () => {
        const toggle = element.lastElementChild;
        toggle.style.maxHeight = toggle.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
}

function hideContent(element) {
    return () => {
        const toggle = element.lastElementChild;
        toggle.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
}

/* Media queries - min width 992px */
loginSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent(loginSection));
loginSection.addEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(loginSection));
searchSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent(searchSection));
searchSection.addEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(searchSection));
shoppingBagSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent(shoppingBagSection));
shoppingBagSection.addEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(shoppingBagSection));
wishlistSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent(wishlistSection));
wishlistSection.addEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(wishlistSection));

/* Media queries - max width 992px */
loginSection.removeEventListener('mouseover', showContent(loginSection));
loginSection.removeEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(loginSection));
searchSection.removeEventListener('mouseover', showContent(searchSection));
searchSection.removeEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(searchSection));
shoppingBagSection.removeEventListener('mouseover', showContent(shoppingBagSection));
shoppingBagSection.removeEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(shoppingBagSection));
wishlistSection.removeEventListener('mouseover', showContent(wishlistSection));
wishlistSection.removeEventListener('mouseout', hideContent(wishlistSection));
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Each time you call hidecontent or showcontent you're creating a new handler, so you're trying to remove a new handler, i.e. one that hasn't been added.

Comment: You have to call `removeEventListener` using a handle to an *existing* function. When you call `showContent()` or `hideContent` you create a *new* function every time.

Comment: What are you expecting the removeEventListener to do? Your mouseout event is currently hiding the loginSection.

Comment: Please describe the weird bug in detail, as event.target should give the same result as using the element.

Answer (score 1):

What is happening is that `return () => {};` is returning a new function every time it's run. So every time you call one of your functions a new event handler is being created.

This means that the handler that is added is different to the one you're trying to remove.

To remedy this, I'd keep it simple:

```
const loginSection = document.querySelector('#js-login-section');

function showContent(e)
{
  const toggle = e.currentTarget.lastElementChild;
  toggle.style.maxHeight = toggle.scrollHeight + 'px';
}

function hideContent(e)
{
  const toggle = e.currentTarget.lastElementChild;
  toggle.style.maxHeight = null;
}

loginSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent);
loginSection.addEventListener('mouseout', hideContent);

loginSection.removeEventListener('mouseover', showContent);
loginSection.removeEventListener('mouseout', hideContent);
```

I'm not sure what you want to avoid repeating, so I can't advise on that, but I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: Thank you, but when I’ll have more "sections" there would be need for variety of specific functions.

Comment: @mdblzk what is the structure of your document? It should be simple to have one function cover showing or hiding for all sections if they have the same structure. Or you can setup a map between the thing you're hovering and the thing you're showing/hiding.

Answer (score 0):

```
const loginSection = document.querySelector('#js-login-section');

function showContent(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    return () => {
        const toggle = element.lastElementChild;
        toggle.style.maxHeight = toggle.scrollHeight + 'px';
    }
}

function hideContent(event) {
    var element = event.target;
    return () => {
        const toggle = element.lastElementChild;
        toggle.style.maxHeight = null;
    }
}

loginSection.addEventListener('mouseover', showContent);
loginSection.addEventListener('mouseout', hideContent);

loginSection.removeEventListener('mouseover', showContent);
loginSection.removeEventListener('mouseout', hideContent);
```

You must set in events method function without call. Element you can get from event `event.target`

Comment: Thank you, I tried that, but it gives me some weird bug so event is not useful for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, I found the following errors,

1. param 'event' will be always undefined - the event should go as a parameter to inner function.
2. you don't need closure here - You can directly assign the function without creating an inner function and access the element with `event.target` or `this`
3. with your implementation, you should pass the same handler reference used in `addEventListener` to `removeEventListener`. So, you should store the handler in a variable and pass it to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`

**Solution:**
if you don't know the handler name, you can use `window.getEventListeners` to do the magic,

`window.getEventListeners` returns a dictionary of events associated with the element.

```js
function removeEventListener(el, eventName) {
  if (!el) {
    throw new Error('Invalid DOM reference passed');
  }

  const listeners = getEventListeners(el)[eventName] || [];

  listeners.forEach(({
    listener
  }) => {
    removeEventListener(eventName, listener);
  });
}

function removeAllEventListener(el) {
  if (!el) {
    throw new Error('Invalid DOM reference passed');
  }

  const events = Object.entries(getEventListeners(el) || {});

  events.forEach(([eventName, listeners]) => {
    listeners.forEach(({
      listener
    }) => {
      removeEventListener(eventName, listener);
    });
  });
}

// example
// remove mouseout event
removeEventListener(loginSection, 'mouseout');
// remove all event listeners 
removeAllEventListener(loginSection);
```